# Unable to configure SAML Identity Provider in Partner Developer

Tags: security, app-development, partner-portal, saml, mydomain

I recently moved my Managed Package Developement from Salesforce Free Developer Org to Salseforce Partner Developer Org due to the additional number of users and API limits they have. I am using my third party app to provide service for salesforce. I am trying to configure Salseforce as Identity Provider and my third party app as Service Provider.

But I coudln't find the Identity Provider link. 
Setup -> Security Controls -> Identity Provider is missing.

My Domain link Under Company Profile is also missing which is essential for Configuring SAML Authentication.

As per salesforce success community I tried creating custom Domains through Salesforce Sites but that doesn't help.

Note:

Free Developer Account works perfect and it had these two links:

- Setup -> Company profile -> My Domain
- Setup -> Security Controls -> Identity provider

I also tried in various test orgs Provided by ISV Portal -> Create test Org but I couldnt see the Identity provider in any of the organizations.

Is there any hidden enable Feature option in ISV portal which will enable IdPs?

**Update**:

I raised a case in ISV Portal and they enabled My Domain feature only for Enterprise Org.
Is there any specific reason why its not avaiable by default ?
Why My Domain cannot be configured in Dev org ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised a case in ISV Portal and I got response saying " Identity Provider cannot be enabled on partner DE Org and will be enabled on Enterprise Edition Org on request"

This is what I inferred:

- In Normal DE Org IDP is enabled out of the box.
- In Partner DE Org IDP cannot be enabled.
- In EE Org IDP will be enabled on request.